# How to modify a complex JSON Object in using Immutable

Tags: reactjs, jsx, immutable.js

I have below JSON and wanted to update the value depending on Aid, Bid and Cid using Immutable.js

e.g. 
Below input provided. 
Aid= A, Bid = 1, Cid= 4, NewValue = 'FOUR'
If above input is provided the value "One" needs to be changed to "FOUR"

```
let sampleJson = {
  Aid: 'A', detail:"sample", list: [
   {
      "Bid": "1",
      "group": [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "Cid": "4",
      "value": "One"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "Cid": "41",
      "value": "1"
    },
  ]
},
{
  "Bid": "2",
  "group": [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "Cid": "4",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "Cid": "4",
      "value": "1"
    },
  ]
};
```

I was able to access the value using below code. How can i return the entire JSON with updated value?

```
let variale = Immutable.fromJS(sampleJson).
getIn(['list']).
find(allocation => allocation.get("Bid") === "1").
getIn(['group']).
find(fun => fun.get("Cid") === "4").set('value',"FOUR");
```

Anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the [setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) method?

Comment: I have looked into setIn method. setIn works when you have a ImmutableMap. It seems when I use Immutable.fromJS above json gets converted to list and map. That is where I am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to do this like so:

```
let immutable = Immutable.fromJS(sampleJson);
immutable = immutable.setIn(['list', 0, 'group', 0, 'value'], 'FOUR');
```

Answer (score 0):

This monstrosity is how I would do it:

```
const newData = originalData.update('list', list => {
  const itemIndex = list.findIndex(item => item.get('Bid') === '2');

  return list.update(itemIndex, listItem => {
    return listItem.update('group', groupList => {
      const groupIndex = list.findIndex(group => group.get('Cid') === '4');

      return groupList.update(groupIndex, group => {
        return group.set('value', 'FOUR');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/latupo/7/edit?html,js,console

Personally I stopped using Immutable, I always found it a bit painful (not to mention those docs!). I now use redux and good old cloning to not mutate state. Less performant in theory but if you've got nothing that runs over a few milliseconds anyway, save yourself the trouble...